# VisualVMのサンプリングスナップショットのNPSファイルの内部構造

Tags: java

VisualVMのサンプリング機能では、スナップショットをNPSファイルとしてエクスポートできます。
このファイルの解析（関心のある部分だけを抽出したりとか）プログラムを作りたいのですが、中身がバイナリなので構造が分かりません。
関数名などが何も見当たらないので、圧縮されているのではないかと思うのですが・・・
どなたかご存知でしょうか。

Comment: 別の形式(CSVやXML)でエクスポートして解析するのではダメなんですかね？

Comment: オープンソース版のVisualVMで見てましたが、OracleJDKについてるVisualVMだと、たしかにCSV出力できますね！　これで要件満たせます。
回答として書いていただけたら、解決済みマークつけます。

Comment: 承知しました。　:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSVやXMLなど別の形式でもエクスポートできるので、それを解析できると思います。

[image: スナップショットのエクスポート]